# please can anyone check this while loop and if condition

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","mts","mts");
if(!con)
{
die('unable to connect' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("mts",$con);

/*
date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Calcutta"); 
$date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo date("d/m/Y h:i:s a", time());
*/

date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Calcutta"); 
$cd=date("d/m/Y");
echo $cd;

echo "<br>";
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","mts","mts");
if(!con)
{
die('unable to connect' . mysql_error());
}
$res=mysql_query("select ElpDur,DateTime from doctor_upload");
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$elp[i]=$row['ElpDur'];
$dt=$row['DateTime'];
//$b[i]=$elp;

echo $elp;
echo "<br>";
echo $dt;

$diff[i]=$cd-$dt;
$a[i]=$elp[i]-$diff[i];
echo $diff[i];
echo $a[i];
if($diff[i]<elp[i])
{
echo $a[i]."days";
}
else
{
echo "expire";
}
$i++;
}


mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: It is customary and polite, to `accept a response` to your questions when possible...  This will continue to encourage folks to look into your long and poorly worded questions :-) ...

Comment: what's the issue that you are facing?

Comment: @mjv …poorly worded and **impossible to read without getting a headache due to missing indention**.

Comment: this kind of codes is the one that make php looks bad and messy compared to other 'well-structured' languages ...

Answer (score 5):

Well, I've looked at it. And you're absolutely right! It's a while loop alright! :)

Comment: If you happen to be looking for a second opinion, I also checked.  It is indeed a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

syntax error here:

```
if($diff[i]<elp[i])
```

must be

```
if($diff[i]<$elp[i])
```

I dont like this part: $diff[i]=$cd-$dt; maybe beter use timestamp for date operations (my subjective opinion)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem too with

```
$elp[i]=$row['ElpDur'];
```

It should look like:

> $elp[$i]=$row['ElpDur'];

Or is "i" a constant?
By the way, you should try to learn [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

If you really want to program code in PHP you´ll have to learn it. Every project is growing, some more some less. The more it grows the more you´ll see that you procedural code is a mess.